# Memory usage in transforming fine tuning of GPTJ-6b to HuggingFace format

Tags: tpu, jax, gpt-3

Following this tutorial using TPUs to fine tune GPTJ has worked well.
https://github.com/kingoflolz/mesh-transformer-jax/blob/master/howto_finetune.md

Why would the step to transform to huggingface format using to_hf_weights.py have an issue with memory at 256MB - even after slimming has been applied?

The issue I filed is here:
https://github.com/kingoflolz/mesh-transformer-jax/issues/209

Answer (score 1):

Resolved by running this step on a standard machine (not TPU) with lots of mem.